# Shopify get current collection

Tags: shopify

I am new to Shopify and learning it right now. I am on collection page, is there a way I can get current collection? For example, I have following collections

```
category 1
    Sub cat 1.1
    Sub cat 1.2
    Sub cat 1.3
category 2
    Sub cat 2.1
    Sub cat 2.2
    Sub cat 2.3
category 3
    Sub cat 3.1
    Sub cat 3.2
    Sub cat 3.3
```

Is there a way I can output this

```
CURRENT Category is: {{collection.name}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `{{ collection.title }}`.

See the [Shopify documentation for `collection` here](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/collection#collection-title).